# Advantages of using MDB2 over straight database functions like mysql_query?

Tags: php, sql, database, mdb2

What are the advantages (and disadvantages) of using the Object-Oriented database library MDB2 over the straight database functions that come with PHP?

Comment: There are also OOP-based layers shipped with PHP. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Being able to use PEAR functions like autoExecute, prepare and query. If you are working a lot with database then you get the advantage of having PEAR escape your data.  It will also handle errors if the value is not the same type expected.

EXAMPLE: You can do multiple inserts, etc. with one statement and an array of values.